# Debugging in intellij sometimes lock my Windows

Tags: windows, debugging, intellij-idea

The following suite of actions locks my Windows 10:

1. Run some java code in debug mode with Intellij
2. wait for a breakpoint to be reached,
3. for whatever reason, I lock my Windows with Windows + L keys,
4. wait for some seconds or minutes
5. log back into my session
6. then, I press F8 to step over my breakpoint.

The last step locks my Windows as if I pressed Windows + L.

Is there any reason why this happens?

This only happens if I follow these steps, a normal debug without locking my session in the process does not lock it again.

Comment: What Windows version do you use? Also please attach information about IDE  from "Help | About".

Comment: I have Windows 10 Pro, version 10.0.1493.

Help | About in intellij shows me this : 

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-181.4445.78, built on April 9, 2018
Licensed to Jordan Noel
Subscription is active until February 18, 2019
For educational use only.
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b27 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0